# How to convert dictionary values into list in Python / Django?

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary

In my Django template, I call this frequently:

```
{% for name, address in directory.addressbook.items %}
  {% for street in address.list %}
    {{street.number}}
```

How do I create this as a filter? I've tried this, but it doesn't work.

In the template, I call:

```
{{directory.addressbook.items|all_numbers}}
```

And in my filter definition I have:

```
def all_numbers(data):
  number_list=[]
  if isinstance(data, dict):
    for name, address in data:
      for street in data.list():
        number_list.append(street)
    return number_list
```

But all I get returned is "[ ]". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if this is part of the problem, but it looks like your outer loop (`for name, address in data:`) is not getting used at all (you don't use `name` or `address`).

Comment: Also, I don't think that `dict` has a `list` attribute.  This *should* raise a syntax error.  since you aren't seeing that it makes me thing that part of the code isn't being executed.  Is `data` empty?  If so, then returning `[]` is correct.

Comment: ah typo, that was meant to be `for street in address.list()`. But I don't get an exception there either - whats the right way to do this? (sorry, i'm new to python)

Comment: Well, `street` might be an object with a `list` method, so that might be OK

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your function as a template filter. Also, this code will need to be in a module and then imported into your template as such...

```
# custom_filters.py
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def all_numbers(data):
  number_list=[]
  if isinstance(data, dict):
    for name, address in data:
      for street in data.list():  # this will raise an exception
        number_list.append(street)
    return number_list

# your-template.html
{% load custom_filters %}

{{ directory.addressbook.items|all_numbers }}
```

Comment: The function is already registered as a filter, else it would raise an exception when I try to call it. I have plenty of other filters that I'm using. Why would "for street in data.list()" raise an exception?